# Include a chunk in a list RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How do you get rmarkdown to include a code chunk as part of a list?

Example:

1. Something about some code - you could try `this_fun`
2. A more complicated way is to do
   ```{r, eval = FALSE}
   a(
     large(
            nested(function)))
   ```
   And that may suit your use case
3. Skip it all together

Originally I was using the vanilla ``` code chunk, but that gives up syntax highlighting, and inline gives up highlighting and newlines/indentation. If the code is used as above the list is broken, and the text following the chunk becomes embedded in a weird environment (something like the output formatting).

Anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for that? 
(Save the following code as Rmd file)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

1. Something about some code - you could try this_fun. 
1. A more complicated way is to do
    ```{r, eval = FALSE}
    a <- function() { # whole chunk indented by 4!
      return(2)
    }
    print(a())
    ```
    And that may suit your use case
1. Skip it all together
````

It look like that:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Christoph, What's special about the four space indent?

Comment: I recommend you to read through the full Pandoc documentation at least once. For this specific issue, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#the-four-space-rule